# Why does Postgres convert an array of two integers into a timestamp?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, timestamp

I'm working with JSON data that may contain formatted timestamps.  I'm converting them to proper timestamps using `cast` when I came across something odd, a conversion that makes no sense:

```
select cast('[112,180]'::json#>>'{}' as timestamp with time zone);
```

Produces a result:

```
         timestamptz          
------------------------------
 0112-06-28 00:00:00+00:53:28
```

The first number is interpreted as the year, and the second number the day of the year, but...
I played a bit an discovered the first integer needs to be >= 100, and the second integer needs to be from 100 to 366. Any other values, and other array lengths will fail.

I'm curious as to why this pattern is parsed as a timestamp?

I'd also be happy to know if there was a way to disable this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is parsed as a timestamp because that is what you explicitly told it to do.

It is not an array of two integers, it is the text string consisting of the sequence of characters `[112,180]`, because that is what `#>>` yields.

It is parsed following the rules [documented here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datetime-input-rules.html) (although it doesn't define what a token is, so that is a bit vague), specifically rule 3d followed by 3b.

Redefining date parsing sounds like a giant mess.  I would think it be better to make a `#>>` variant that throws an ERROR (if that is what you want, you didn't say what you wanted to happen, only what you wanted not to happen) when the json_typeof from `#>` is not string.

Comment: I'd be happy if an error was thrown if the type was not a string. I'm wrapping this call already in a function with exception handling. It'd be nice if it only converted strings.